# make on click responsive sub menu display on hover

Tags: jquery, css

this sub menu is displayed on click for small devices(320px). make this sub menu appear on hover for large devices(1024px).

jquery

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('ul.subcat').hide();

       $('li').click(function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         $('> ul', this).toggle();
       });
     });
   </script>
```

Comment: do you have any question?

Comment: if by "devices" you mean mobile devices, care to explain what is 'hover' on a mobile device?

Comment: You may be interested in [these](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries) [links](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/jquery-and-css-media-queries).

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
        $(".selector").click(function(){

            //Your Code

    }); 
    }else
    {
        $(".selector").hover(function(){

             //Your Code

        });         
    }
});
```

you can get the functionality by this. Try this.

Comment: I want hover for media (max-width:1024px) not for mobile device

Comment: For the (max-width: 1024px) you can use this hover event.

Comment: Thanks Suyesh. I want the sub menu display on hover for (max-width:1024px) media and on click for (max-width:320px) media. just want to make menu responsive.

Comment: i also got to know that sub menu behavior can be changed in jquery using $(window). resize(function() for responsive design. could this make sub menu display differently for different media sizes?